# How can I stop regex matching dates as digits

Tags: ruby, regex

Given this string:

```
stuff = "banana 11/12/2009 123"
```

how can I get regex in a ruby .scan call to only return:

```
["123"]
```

In ruby I've used `stuff.scan(/\b\d+\b/)` but realized that the \b boundary sees the backslashes as boundaries so I get ["11","12","2009","123"] returned from the method. Also I need the scan to deal with the following and only return "123" :

```
stuff = "123 banana 11/12/2009"
stuff = "11/12/2009 banana 123"
```

Any ideas anyone? :)

Comment: What is your criterion that makes you want to match certain numbers and not others?

Comment: So the background to this is that I'm writing a unified search which needs to be smart enough to run integers against certain fields in an underlaying postgresql database, dates against another field and text strings against a fulltext search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this pattern:

```
/(?<=\s|^)\d+(?=\s|$)/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)
```

Which is equivalent to (but slightly shorter):

```
(?<=\s|^)\d+(?=\s|$)
```

That is match `\d+` which has spaces around it, or start/end of string (or line).

Answer (score 2):

You could also try for the more readable split/select solution that looks for just digits in a space separated section of text.

```
stuff.split.select { |x| x =~ (/^\d+$/)}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Negative lookahead/behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?<!/)\b\d+\b(?!/)
```

Escaping for Ruby if you use `/` as the delimiter

```
(?<!\/)\b\d+\b(?!\/)
```

Demo: http://rubular.com/r/P9MjQ87csO

Note: If you use `/` all the time for regex, then I suggest you look at changing your delimiter. According to [this dailyvim post](http://dailyvim.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/leaning-toothpick-syndrome.html), you can do it this way:

```
mystring =~ %r{(?<!/)\b\d+\b(?!/)}
```

And never worry about forward slashes again. See [Leaning Toothpick Syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome)

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't get this one to work at all? Is there a syntax error the the line?

Comment: No, it is valid regex, but I'm not a Rubyer so I haven't escaped any characters; if you use `/` to delimit a regex then you'll need to escape the two instances of it thus: `(?<!\/)\b\d+\b(?!\/)`. Or you may need to check Ruby's support for lookaround.

Comment: @NeilBillingham I've updated the post to reflect my views on leaning toothpicks.

Answer (score 1):

You want a stand-alone, three digit string at the start or end of the containing string:

```
/(?:^\d{3}\b|\b\d{3}$)/
```

Here is the [proof](http://rubular.com/r/mRyZuoL92D) for the regex.

Comment: Nice one thanks :) Thanks for regex expression editor link too :)

Answer (score 0):

how about trying to negate the / ?

```
stuff.scan(/[^\/]*\d[^\/]*/)
```

Comment: ummmm.. this seems to match everything except the slashes in the date - thanks anyhow :)